# Difference between browsing messages or just get them one by one

Tags: ibm-mq

For IBM MQ it is possible to use `MQGET` to browse messages on a queue (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=queue-browsing-messages) or just do a 'normal' `MQGET` (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=queue-getting-messages-from-using-mqget-call)

I cannot find any differences in what a browse does (except using a cursor) and a normal get does, in terms of what content is being retrieved.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general a normal get is destructive and the message is permanently removed from the queue, a browse is not deductive and does not remove the message from the queue.  The message content returned is the same in either case.

There are three basic situations:

1. A get with the browse option does not remove the message from the queue, it is still available for other consumers to get or browse from the queue.
2. A normal get outside of a unit of work will remove the message from the queue, it will not be available for other consumers to get or browse from the queue.
3. A normal get inside of a unit of work will make the message unavailable for other consumers to get or browse from the queue.

   - If the unit of work is committed the message will be removed from the queue, it will not be available for other consumers to get or browse from the queue.
   - If the unit of work is backed out the message will be available again for other consumers to get or browse from the queue.